# no value from firebase firestore when using orderBy() in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build a group chat app using dart-flutter in android studio . Everything was smooth until I needed to display the messages in the order of time they were sent . For that i created a field "timestamp" in firebase and i also passed the timestamp using "FieldValue.serverTimestamp()" , but when i try to use the "timestamp" by using orderBy() .. i don't get the mesages displayed , instead it tells that there is no value(null) but when I try to access the messages without using orderBy() then it works fine

Take a look at the widget where i passed the "FieldValue.serverTimestamp()" to "timestamp" :

```
        @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       leading: null,
       actions: <Widget>[
         IconButton(
             icon: Icon(Icons.close),
             onPressed: () {
               _auth.signOut();
               Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
               //Implement logout functionality
             }),
       ],
       title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
       backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
     ),
     body: SafeArea(
       child: Column(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
         children: <Widget>[
           // ignore: missing_return
           messageStream(firestore: _firestore),
           Container(
             decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
             child: Row(
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
               children: <Widget>[
                 Expanded(
                   child: TextField(
                     controller: messageTextController,
                     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                     onChanged: (value) {
                       messageText = value;
                       //Do something with the user input.
                     },
                     decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                   ),
                 ),
                 TextButton(
                   onPressed: () {
                     messageTextController.clear();
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add(
                       {'text': messageText, 'sender': loggedIn.email,'timestamp':FieldValue.serverTimestamp()},
                     );

                   },
                   child: Text(
                     'Send',
                     style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                   ),
                 ),
               ],
             ),
           ),
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Also check the widget where i tried to use the orderBy()

```
class messageStream extends StatelessWidget {
  messageStream({
    @required this.firestore,
  }) ;
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(

        stream: firestore.collectionGroup('messages').orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).snapshots(),
        // ignore: missing_return
        builder: (context, snapshot) {

            final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
            List<messageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
            for (var message in messages) {
              final messageText = message.data()['text'];
              final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];

             if(_auth.currentUser.email == messageSender){
               final meassageBubble = messageBubble(text: messageText, sender: messageSender , crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,textColor: Colors.white , topLeft: Radius.circular(30),topRight: Radius.circular(0),);
               messageBubbles.add(meassageBubble);
             }
             else{
               final meassageBubble = messageBubble(text: messageText, sender: messageSender , crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,color: Colors.white,textColor: Colors.black , topLeft: Radius.circular(0),topRight: Radius.circular(30));
               messageBubbles.add(meassageBubble);
             }
            }
            return Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                reverse: true ,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20 ,horizontal: 15),
                child: Column(children: messageBubbles)
              ),
            );

        });
  }
}
```

Finally I have also attached the chat screen (emulator) image(screenshot) where it tells that there is no value

[image]

Further if you have any questions or if you need further details about the code you can ask me

Comment: you have to write an index in firestore, somtimes is showed as link in console

Answer (score 1):

you have to create index in firebase console, flutter will provide link in your log:

[image]

then select create index
[image]

Comment: But it requires two fields , I only need to access the "timestamp" field ...  I have created index  with the help of  another field , but the same error is coming (docs have no value)..

Comment: it will provide two links follow both and click create index

Comment: Where is the link ?

Comment: in your flutter log it will generate a link see my answer